# GluonTS example airpassengers dataset not found

Tags: time-series, forecasting, deepar

I am trying to run the GluonTS example code, going through some struggle to install the libraries, now I get the following error:

`FileNotFoundError: C:\Users\abcde\.mxnet\gluon-ts\datasets\airpassengers\test`

The `C:\Users\abcde\.mxnet\gluon-ts\datasets\airpassengers\` does exist but contains only `train` folder. Have tried reinstalling but to no avail. Any ideas how to fix this and run the example, even if finding the dataset in correct format elsewhere?

EDIT: To clarify, I was referring to an example on https://ts.gluon.ai/stable/

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gluonts.dataset.util import to_pandas
from gluonts.dataset.pandas import PandasDataset
from gluonts.dataset.repository.datasets import get_dataset
from gluonts.mx import DeepAREstimator, Trainer

dataset = get_dataset("airpassengers")

deepar = DeepAREstimator(prediction_length=12, freq="M", trainer=Trainer(epochs=5))
model = deepar.train(dataset.train)

# Make predictions
true_values = to_pandas(list(dataset.test)[0])
true_values.to_timestamp().plot(color="k")

prediction_input = PandasDataset([true_values[:-36], true_values[:-24], true_values[:-12]])
predictions = model.predict(prediction_input)

for color, prediction in zip(["green", "blue", "purple"], predictions):
    prediction.plot(color=f"tab:{color}")

plt.legend(["True values"], loc="upper left", fontsize="xx-large")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an incorrect import on the earlier version of the example, which was since corrected, also I needed to specify `regenerate=True` while getting the dataset, so:

`dataset = get_dataset("airpassengers", regenerate=True)`.